# Android code to play .wav files located in res/raw - weird errors

Tags: java, android, audio

I've been stuck on this particular problem for a while now, and it's something that should be really simple so it's annoying.. I must be misusing the Android API somehow?

Here is the code:

```
  try {
  String packageName = getPackageName(); 
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier( "filename" , "raw" , packageName ); //in res/raw folder I have filename.wav audio file
  mp.setDataSource("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + resID);
  mp.prepare();
  mp.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

The toast message I see says:

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC
```

In eclipse logcat I see:

```
MediaPlayer Error (-4 -4)
```

Much thanks to anyone who can help with this... I just want to play my wav files darn it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a FileDescriptor instead:

```
String packageName = getPackageName(); 
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier( "filename" , "raw" , packageName );
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(resId);
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
afd.close();
```

That's what I always do and it's safer to do it that way rather than hardcoding a path.

Comment: Remember `afd.close();` after `mp.start();`.

Comment: No problem. :) And good call @eightx2, I actually didn't realize those needed to be closed, thanks for the tip!